# Delaying stream of values in Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, delay

I could really use some help with delaying a stream of data pulled from a FIFO pipe. I'm building a music visualizer where the program pulls in frequency bar height data from the pipe. However, there is some latency with my bluetooth speaker, so I need to delay the bar height data for ~0.5s so that the visuals can sync up with the audio. Here's a quick [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pN_DrBzOmBypUMkPRU9wPtL1mkpJTd-T/view) demonstrating my visualizer with a wired speaker so you can get an idea of how it should work with the bluetooth speaker.

A simple time.delay() won't do the trick since that would create a 0.5s gap between each data point, which would kill the stream. I need a steady stream that flows constantly, just 0.5s after it comes in.

I thought I could use multiprocessing to call a delayer method without waiting for it to return, thus creating that constant stream of evenly delayed values. However, when I run this code (pasted below), the program just gets overwhelmed and everything freezes. Any advice on my code or on a better way to achieve the outcome would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
def delayer(dstring):
    time.sleep(.5)
    print(dstring)

while True:
    fd1 = open(thepath,'rb')
    for line in fd1:
    
        stringvals = line.decode("utf-8")
        t = multiprocessing.Process(target=delayer,args=(stringvals,))
        t.start()
```

Comment: look into generators https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators  with time.sleep

Comment: @frozen thanks for the suggestion! where were you thinking I could put the time.sleep? If i put it in a loop that calls the generator, it'll space out each value by the delay which isn't what I want. Is there a way to put it within the generator?

Comment: I was able to work around it by creating an array of size 25 and using numpy to roll the values each time around, so the visuals would be 25 frames behind which synced up with the audio